# A word or phrase describing "cheap talk" or "cheap issues"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Cheap talk like a kind of talking back of actors'/actresses' lives or an interview about their secret lives in some popular magazines or cheesy show off like reality shows you can find in TV channels. Making a drama or love story of any simple or ordinary happening in its fake version only to take attention or advertise for someone or something.

We have an interesting equal in Persian/Farsi language which is "Yellow Matters". Do you have something like this for it?

Comment: Are you talking about "gossip"?

Comment: No. An equal for Yellow Matters in Farsi language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Sensationalism"*** for starters and ***"tabloid reporting"*** for another - both of which are extremely popular in our society at this time.

> Definition of ***"sensational"*** from M-W.com:
>
> 2 : arousing or
> tending to arouse (as by lurid details) a quick, intense, and usually
> superficial interest, curiosity, or emotional reaction ex.:
> sensational tabloid news

Comment: Kristina Lopez, Thanks! I think it is the best answer up to now however it cannot cover all the matter but better than before.May I have to add some new phrases to English language in the future! :))

Comment: Thanks @SnowFlake! New words, like new toys, are always fun!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are describing [*yellow journalism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_journalism):

> **Yellow journalism**, or the **yellow press**, is a type of journalism that presents little or no legitimate well-researched news and instead uses eye-catching headlines to sell more newspapers. Techniques may include exaggerations of news events, scandal-mongering, or sensationalism. By extension, the term *yellow journalism* is used today as a pejorative to decry any journalism that treats news in an unprofessional or unethical fashion.

Comment: Yellow journalism can be part of it but I want a better word/phrase which includes all my above examples from magazines,TV channels,reality shows and ordinary people if there is an equal to cover all of them. It is not only about unwanted realities or hidden secrets but about something cheap,fake and low-value which some of people make a business upon it.

Comment: @SnowFlake Trash talk?

Comment: Maybe! I am waiting for more suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

'Hype' is what is used in the context of celebrities.  The media will take a small incident and blow it all out of proportion.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hype